# Drupal Commerce does not allow any payment if payment pane is not in review order page

Tags: commerce

If I do not put the *Payment* pane in the *Review Order* page, then no payment method works and it just goes to checkout complete. Even if I check *Require a payment method at all times* it makes no difference.

Is this a bug or is it something I'm missing?

The attached image works but not when payment is in **payment** when it is it skips payment entirely.

[image: image_capture]

Comment: What is the desired payment workflow there?

Comment: Hi, I have attached an image to earlier post of the workflow which currently works.

Have rechecked this morning and moving the payment pane to payment disables the payment method regardless of whether 'Require a payment method at all times' is checked. Thanks

Comment: The desired workflow is that the user is allowed to enter their payment info and complete checkout. When "payment" pane appears anywhere prior to "review order", the payment posts and the order gets marked as completed before the review step, and the user cannot complete checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess 'payment' means 'choose payment method'

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a very old question, but I think that since the Payment page is normally not shown (it's only for redirecting to offsite payment), moving the Payment pane there (which as charlesd mentions, is where you choose the payment method) just never shows up and skips directly to the Checkout Complete page.

It's possible to move the Payment pane to another page earlier in the checkout sequence, just not to the Payment page.